# Admin view/edit content as user

Tags: database, entities, users

Is it possible to toggle an admin role to see and edit content as a specific user?

I've got a number of entityreferences with contextual filters that are URL dependent, and when I try to edit an entityform submission as admin, I can only see my own data view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think  you are looking for this module [Masquerade](https://www.drupal.org/project/masquerade).

> The Masquerade module allows site administrators (or anyone with enough permissions) to switch users and surf the site as that user (no password required). That person can switch back to their own user account at any time.

There is a module called [Role Toggle](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_toggle) to handle role toggle.

> This module gives you a page and a block to toggle (switch on and off) any role.